# Need A Form Process To Automatically Re-Name Uploaded Photo

Tags: php, forms, file-upload, buffer, file-rename

ISSUE:

I have a php buffering code that 'names' my form-generated .html pages, based on the data in one of the form fields in my form.

```
<!--Start Buffer->
<?php ob_start(); $URL=preg_replace('#[^_0-9a-zA-Z]#', '_', $_REQUEST['timeValue']); ?>
```

That particular form field is auto-populated with the current unix millisecond clock.

```
    <!--FormPage-->
    <!--Timevalue/Unix millisecond code/field->

    <div class="formElement">TIMESTAMP URL<br><input id="timeValue" name="timeValue"></div>
    <script src="timeValueURL.js"></script>
```

Therefore... my .html files are ultimately saved with a 'name' (ie. number), which is the same as whatever the 'milliseconds' were at the moment my form was 'submitted'.

*Note: My 'submit' button also 'updates' the millisecond clock on submit.

The generated .html files are then saved to one of the valid directories; 'categories/news', 'categories/sports' or 'categories/entertainment'.

So, (Example) If the .html file is saved to the 'news' directory... and the millisecond clock was at '1500000000000' when the form was submitted... the .html file would have a url 'mywebsite.com/categories/news/1500000000000.html'

---

In the same form... I have a file upload field for my visitors to upload an image file from their own server/device.

Note: The permitted image file types are limited to JPEG, PNG and GIF.

Those uploaded images are saved in a folder named 'categories-images'.

Currently... those image files are saved to that folder under the 'name' they had when they were uploaded.

Example: If a user uploads a JPEG image named 'blueimage.jpg', the file would currently be saved at the url 'mywebsite.com/categories/category-images/blueimage.jpg'.

Instead... I would like the image file to share the same 'name' as the .html file.

So, using the above example... the image should have a name of '1500000000000.jpg' and have a url address of

'mywebsite.com/categories/category-images/1500000000000.jpg'.

---

QUESTION:

Is there a way to achieve this similar to, or perhaps even incorporating the code used in naming the .html file?

---

NOTE:

It occurred to me that I should include the php for image handling as well.

So here that is....

```
<?php 
    $target_dir = "articles/article-images/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]); $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]); 
        if($check !== false)
        {
            echo "" . $check[""] . ""; $uploadOk = 1;
        } 
        else
        {
            echo "  &#xd7; FILE IS NOT AN IMAGE"; $uploadOk = 0;
        } 
    }
    if(file_exists($target_file))
    {
        echo "  &#xd7; THIS IMAGE ALREADY EXIST ON SERVER"; $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000)
    {
        echo "  &#xd7; FILE IS TOO LARGE"; $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" )
    {
        echo "   &#xd7; ONLY JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF FILES ARE PERMITTED"; $uploadOk = 0; 
    }
    if ($uploadOk == 0)
    {
        echo "  &#xd7; IMAGE WAS NOT UPLOADED";
    }
    else
    {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file))
        {
            echo '<img class="fixed-ratio-resize" src="../../articles/article-images/'. basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). '">';
        } 
        else
        {
            echo "  &#xd7; IMAGE WAS NOT UPLOADED";
        }
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just have to take the name of the html file *(the milliseconds, where ever that code is)* and replace the `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]`. I'm going to reference that value as `$millisecs` with the extension `$imageFileType`:

```
<?php
# Presumably this whole thing is based off a post, so just check at the top
if(!isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    # Let the user know, this this can not be accessed without a submission
    die('Nothing submitted.');
}
# Set the extension first since you aren't going to use the name
$imageFileType  =  pathinfo($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
# Set dir
$target_dir = "articles/article-images/";
# Add your milliseconds carried over from your html script. Add extension,
# this will be the new name
$target_file = $target_dir.$millisecs.".{$imageFileType}"; 
# Default affermative
$uploadOk = 1;
# Get image size
$check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]); 
if($check !== false) {
    # I am not suer what this is...it doesn't look like you should echo
    # anything at all...
    echo "".$check[""]."";
    $uploadOk = 1;
}
else {
    echo "  &#xd7; FILE IS NOT AN IMAGE";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

if(file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "  &#xd7; THIS IMAGE ALREADY EXIST ON SERVER";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "  &#xd7; FILE IS TOO LARGE";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
# Set allowed file types
$allowed = array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif');
#Check if type is in list
if(!in_array(strtolower($imageFileType),$allowed)) {
    echo "   &#xd7; ONLY JPG/JPEG, PNG & GIF FILES ARE PERMITTED";
    $uploadOk = 0; 
}

if($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "  &#xd7; IMAGE WAS NOT UPLOADED";
}
else {
    # Move the temp file to the new name here
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        # Write the basename of the new file here
        echo '<img class="fixed-ratio-resize" src="../../articles/article-images/'. basename($target_file). '">';
    } 
    else {
        echo "  &#xd7; IMAGE WAS NOT UPLOADED";
    }
}
```